# QuickTime loading new movie not scaling

Tags: quicktime

I have the following code, mainly copied from Apple's QT Guide, which I use to display a few movies:

```
<noscript>
<object id="video_obj" TARGETCACHE="true" width="480" height="320" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
  <param name="src" value="images/loginbig.gif" />
  <param name="controller" value="true" />
  <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
  <param name="postdomevents" value="true" />
  <param name="TARGETCACHE", value="true"/ >
  <embed src="images/loginbig.gif"
    width="480" height="320"
    controller="true" autoplay="false"
    scale="aspect" cache="true"
    name="video_obj"
    id="video_obj_embed"
    postdomevents="true"
    TARGETCACHE="true"
    pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
   />
</object>
</noscript>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    QT_WriteOBJECT('images/loginbig.gif' , '480', '320', ''
    ,'id','video_obj'
    ,'controller', 'true'
    ,'postdomevents', 'true'
    ,'cache', 'true'
    ,'autoplay', 'false'
    ,'emb#id','video_obj_embed'
    ,'emb#scale','aspect'
    ,'name', 'video_obj'
    ,'type', 'video/quicktime'
    ,'scale', 'aspect'
   );

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var video = document.video_obj;
</script>
```

I change video by doing

```
video.SetURL('http://dns.com/video.mp4');
```

But if the new video's size is larger than the preset width and height, it won't automatically fit to the video screen, I tried everything I can think of and read up but to no avail.  Please do share your advice on how one may tackle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have aspect defined in the embed tag, but not in the params. I think you may need to add this: `<param name="scale" value="aspect" />`

Comment: Hey John, I tried that but it didn't work. thanks for the response, though, it's pretty empty here for quicktime related quesiton it looks like

Answer (score 1):

To keep the parameters from the plugin initialization for other videos, use 'SAVEEMBEDTAGS','true'

```
QT_WriteOBJECT('logo.mov' , '720', '576', '', 
'EnableJavaScript', 'True',
'emb#NAME' , 'movie1' ,
'obj#id' , 'movie1',
'controller', 'false' ,
'scale', 'tofit',
'SAVEEMBEDTAGS','true' ) ;
```